How to send args **kwargs to func in apscheduler
I try set args to function in apscheduler and got error.
I try this code:
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
current_job = scheduler.add_job(back_shops_tasks(company), id='shops_back', trigger='interval', minutes=15)
scheduler.start()`

and got this error:

TypeError: func must be a callable or a textual reference to one

How I can send *args, **kwargs to func apscheduler?

Looking at the docs is faster than asking here and waiting for an answer, and should be the first thing you do anyway

@pho maybe you didn't understand the question or maybe its pmc

I can only guess, but I am assuming that you want to schedule a function called back_shops_tasks. Currently you are directly calling the function with argument company and give the result to the scheduler.
According to the docs, you should call it like this:
current_job = scheduler.add_job(back_shops_tasks, args=..., kwargs=... id='shops_back', trigger='interval', minutes=15)

Replace ... accordingly for args and kwargs. args must be a list or a tuple, kwargs is a dict, e.g., args=[company]. If you do not actually need kwargs, just remove them again from the function call again or replace ... by None.

Thanks, But question is how to send *args **kwargs to function back_shops_tasks ?

Yes, this is precisely what my answer does. the (kw)args will be applied to the function inside the add_job call. just try it out

@АндрейИзотов glad it works for you, please accept my answer then ;-)
